# Javascript email error with prettyphoto

Tags: ajax

Im using prettyphoto to create a staff popout info page when a staff photo is clicked.

Pretty photo calls another template via ajax, which works ok except for the staff email which outputs an error: 'JavaScript must be enabled to view this email address'.
The code in the ajax popup is as follows:

```
<div class="modal">
{exp:channel:entries channel="leadershipteam" disable="categories|trackbacks|pagination" sort="asc" entry_id="{embed:entry_id}" limit="1"}
<img src="{colourphoto}" class="leftimage"><h1>{title}</h1><h2>{staff_title}</h2>
<p>{staffdescription}</p>
<br /><strong>{if staff_email} E: {staff_email}<br><br>{/if}{if staff_phone}P: {staff_phone}<br />{/if}</strong>
{/exp:channel:entries}
{clear}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't serve javascript via AJAX -- and the email address is being automatically encoded as Javascript to protect it from spammers.

The way around this is to turn off "[Automatically turn URLs and email addresses into links?](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/channels/channel_edit_preferences.html#automatically-turn-urls-and-email-addresses-into-links)" in the channel preferences.

TTFN
Travis